# Locking a file when using multiprocessing and multithreading - Python

Tags: python, multithreading, file, locking, multiprocessing

I have a `main.py` file. This file uses `multiprocessing` to execute another file called `function.py`. The second one use `threading` to apply a function, `f`, to every component of a `numpy array`. `function.py` reads (only once in all the process) a file, `file.txt`, to read some data for `f` and then to clear it (write a empty file). Do I need to lock the file, `file.txt`, in `function.py` to avoid problems of having `N` processes, created from `main.py` executing `function.py` and reading and writing in `file.txt`? If so, how can it be done?

Finally I get it with a [`semaphore`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#semaphore-objects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in some way it has to be locked.
Having several processes reading a file is no problem as long as they are only reading it. As soon as something writes to the file you have to be sure that the reads and writes occur in the desired order.

Locking could be done by using a lockfile that is atomically created. After a process successfully creates the lockfile, it gains access to the text file. After the process is done with the text file, it deletes the lockfile. This assures that only one process can access the text file at a given time.

Comment: You can also synchronize your process inside the program to make sure only one process at a time accesses the code where the file is edited.

Comment: best answer to the question